# Why does "cp -R --reflink=always" perform a standard copy on a Btrfs filesystem?

Tags: btrfs, cp, copy-on-write, reflink

Btrfs support Copy-On-Write. I tried to use that feature to clone a directory:

```
cp -R --reflink=always foo_directory foo_directory.mirror
```

I expected the command to finish almost instantly (like a `btrfs subvolume snapshot`), but the `cp` command seems to perform a slow, standard copy.

According to the man page, I would expected `--reflink=always` to enforce Copy-On-Write:

> When `--reflink[=always]` is specified, perform a lightweight copy, where the data blocks are copied only when modified. If this is not possible the copy fails, or if `--reflink=auto` is specified, fall back to  a standard copy.

**Questions:**

- Do you know why `--reflink=always` doesn't work?
- What options (or other commands) should I use instead?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`cp --reflink=always` is almost certainly working correctly. If it weren't, you would be getting an error. By design, that's the difference between `--reflink=always` and `--reflink=auto`. The error would look like this:

```
# Filesystem that does not support the feature at all
cp: failed to clone `xx' from `yy': Inappropriate ioctl for device

# Filesystem that does support it, but copy across filesystems
cp: failed to clone `xx' from `yy': Invalid cross-device link
```

Are you copying a directory structure with lots of small files? In that case `cp` still has to create every directory and open and close every file, so it will still take time, unlike `btrfs subvolume snapshot`. That most likely explains the time it takes to perform the operation.

Comment: Yes, it contains a huge number of files, most of them small text files. I did not know that cp still has to process every file. Thanks, that was the part that I did not understand. I think in my use case, it is better to create a writable snapshot.

Comment: Yeah, if you can create a snapshot then go for it. `cp --reflink=always` can still come in handy when what you're trying to clone is not the root of a subvolume, since `btrfs subvolume snapshot` only operates on subvolumes, not on portions of subvolumes.